# Which Data Augmentation options you recommend in Tensorflow API (Object Detection)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

This answer contains the list of all Data Augmentation values [What are possible values for data_augmentation_options in the TensorFlow Object Detection pipeline configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906317/what-are-possible-values-for-data-augmentation-options-in-the-tensorflow-object)

I am training a model to detect objects like Gun, Knife etc. I would like to know, which objects you will use (for sure and maybe).

I am expecting an answer like this:

> I will for sure use:
>
> ```
> RandomAdjustBrightness , RandomAdjustContrast, RandomAdjustHue
> ```
>
> I might also try:
>
> ```
> ScaleBoxesToPixelCoordinates, RandomResizeMethod
> ```