# Tensorflow object detection - issue with making changes to config file

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am working with EfficentDet and Tensorflow object detection API and have some problems
with changing the config file.

It works fine for this:

```py
config_dic = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(fpath)

config_dic["model"].ssd.num_classes = len(LabelMap)
config_dic["model"].ssd.image_resizer.keep_aspect_ratio_resizer.min_dimension = 512

config_dic["train_config"].batch_size = 1
config_dic["train_config"].fine_tune_checkpoint = os.path.join(path, model_name, "checkpoint/ckpt-0")
config_dic["train_config"].fine_tune_checkpoint_type = "detection"
config_dic["train_config"].use_bfloat16 = False # Set to True if training on a TPU
config_dic["train_config"].num_steps = 10000

config_dic["train_input_config"].label_map_path = path_label
config_dic["train_input_config"].tf_record_input_reader.input_path[:] = train_data

config_dic["eval_input_configs"][0].label_map_path = path_label
config_dic["eval_input_configs"][0].tf_record_input_reader.input_path[:] = valid_data

config_dic["model"].ssd.image_resizer.keep_aspect_ratio_resizer.pad_to_max_dimension = False
config_dic["model"].ssd.image_resizer.keep_aspect_ratio_resizer.max_dimension = 1024
```

But running this give me an error:

```py
config_dic["train_config"].data_augmentation_options.random_horizontal_flip = False
config_dic["train_config"].data_augmentation_options.random_adjust_brightness = 0.4
config_dic["train_config"].data_augmentation_options.random_adjust_contrast = [0.6, 1.5]
config_dic["train_config"].data_augmentation_options.random_jitter_boxes = 0.1
config_dic["train_config"].data_augmentation_options.random_rotation90 = 0.5
```

```py
'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer' object has no attribute 'random_horizontal_flip'
```

and similar errors for the others too.

(I have tried with integers instead of False and get the same error message)

which is weird since i have this in the config file:

```py
train_config {
  batch_size: 1
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

edit (added some requested information):

I am using tensorflow 2.4.1 and protobuf 3.12.2

The only code that comes after the changes of the config file are:

```py
# Save changes
config = config_util.create_pipeline_proto_from_configs(config_dic)
config_util.save_pipeline_config(config, dst)

# Train
!python workspace/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=$dst --pipeline_config_path=$fpath
```

Answer (score 0):

according to https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto random_horizontal_flip should take an integer, not a boolean.

Please also see [What are possible values for data_augmentation_options in the TensorFlow Object Detection pipeline configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906317/what-are-possible-values-for-data-augmentation-options-in-the-tensorflow-object).

Comment: I have tried an integer but that does not work either, it seems like instead it doesnt recognize random_horizontal_flip or any of the other things i tried.

Comment: @JKnecht Mhh too bad. Can you tell us which protobuf version and which tensorflow version you are using?

Comment: and please also share the code that uses the config. Maby there is a hint there ...